# Discord.js open DM stream with certain user by ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there any option to open a `DM stream` or something like that with certain user by ID.

> What do I mean?

It's like ssh terminal function, when I enter command to bot like:

```
me: DM@{user.id}
bot: {connection established message}
/**--------------------------------------------
@ and for now, every message from me, bot will deliver to {user.id} until I 
@ don't send `{message_stop}` command, for example:
----------------------------------------------*/
me: "Hi, how are you?" -> client.fetchUser('user_id')
me: "Are you ok?"
me: -stop command
```

Without using -prefix every time in the beginning of each message?

Or probably implement this function like that:

> Creating a channel on server(guild) and every message that I write there, will be delivered to a certain user?

**The actual question is, if it's possible then how should I manipulate [with `client.on('trigger')` state](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) to achieve such result?**

As for now, I have written the command, which DMs message to user, based on prefix in the begging of each message like:

```
me: dm@user_id: Hello!
me: dm@user_id: How are you?
```

Probably I should store session data (user.id) somewhere, to help bot understood that I want to communicate only with specific user?

Comment: There's no such thing as a DM stream. You'll have to check for the [message](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-message) event that is emitted when the bot sees a message. Using the property [guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=guild), find if it doesn't have a guild (so it must be a DM). With a stored user ID, check if the said message is from that stored user ID. I hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: As @Steamgamer stated, you can't create a DM Stream in the same sense you can an Opus Audio Stream. In order to create a DM Channel with another user, you'd need to run the function `createDM()` against a user object. You can obtain the user object either through the `message` event emitted from the client, or invoking it manually via a command of which you tag the user in. As documented [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), on the `guildMemberAdd` event you're returned a `GuildMember` type, of which you can do `member.createDM()`. Keep in mind it's a promise.

Comment: @Steamgamer, @Brxxn, seems you understood it's wrong guys. I was asking about text direct-messages stream. No voice audio. And the `MessageCollector` is a perfect solution here.

Comment: We understand correctly, we were not commenting about audio streams, but the text gained from direct messages. `MessageCollector`s are great if the messages are expected to be short term with an expected duration, but that's not a limitation of the `message` event.

Comment: Well, but you could `limit` with so great value by time or message counts, that you'll receive endless stream. And also stop it, at any time you want, just by sending any command to command to bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I receive this answer in `Discord.js` discord. So it's possible with [MessageCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageCollector). I'm using [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector) for building my bot [with dynamic commands](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/dynamic-commands.html). So here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'direct',
    description: 'Ping!',
    args: true,
    execute(message, args, client) {
        const u = message.content.split(/(?<=^\S+)@/)[1];
        console.log(message.content);
        message.channel.send(`Connection established: ${message.author.id}`);
        const filter = m => m.content.includes('discord');
        const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, {
            maxMatches: 10,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time']
        });

        collector.on('collect', m => {
            console.log(`${Date.now()} Collected ${m.content}`);
            client.fetchUser('user_id').then((user) => {
                return user.send(`${m.content}`);
            });
        });

        collector.on('end', collected => {
            message.channel.send(`Connection cancelled with ${message.author.id}. You send ${collected.size} messages`);
            console.log(`${Date.now()} Collected ${collected.size} items`);
            if (collected.size === 0) {
                console.log('here');
            }
        });
    }
};
```

You just enter command name (direct) in this case, and then every message that incudes `discord` DMs to user_id 10 times or for 30 seconds. You could use arguments, if you want to change it. Hope it helps anyone.

Also, I'm very thankful to Monbrey#4502 from Discord.js community for providing this information.